# Use extended REST functions like contains in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, rest, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, dynamics-crm

As I noticed, fetching data in Dynamics CRM with REST is a lot faster then with SOAP especially for big data.

Since I'm new to this topic (REST) I want to ask if it's necessary to include any additional library to use functions in my query for instance "contains".

If I send the query:

```
XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.RetrieveMultiple("ActivityPointerSet", 
"$filter=contains(Subject,'Test')&$top=10", 
function(results){ 
    console.log(results);
}, 
function(error){
    console.log(error);
},
function onComplete(){

}, false);
```

I get the error message: Error : 400: Bad Request: Unknown function 'contains' at position 0.

I got more or less intricate queries yet with fetchXML. Is it in most cases possible to alter them to REST?

Best Regards

Comment: Dynamics CRM only supports a limited subset of the OData specification. Take a look at the CRM SDK or the documentation on MSDN. Dynamics CRM 2016 introduces Web API and a more complete implementation of OData v4.

Comment: For reference, here's the 2011 SDK's page on the operators: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461(v=crm.5).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the `C# QueryExpression` functions in `Odata Queries` directly. You have to modify them according to `Odata Syntax/Functions`.

Please change your query to below and try again:

```
select=*&$filter=substringof('Test',Subject)&$top=10
```

A very good tool to generate complex `Odata Queries`is
[Dynamics XRM Tools](http://dynamicsxrmtools.codeplex.com/)

[image]
 [Adding Selection Criteria to REST Queries in CRM 2011](https://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/02/22/adding-selection-criteria-to-rest-queries/)